# Resizing UIScrollView to fit its content… not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have an app that uses a UIScrollView to display content created by Interface Builder. I add a UITextView to it programmatically because its content is changeable and I want it to resize. This is done! The problem comes when resizing the UIScrollView to fit the new UITextView size. I just can't get it done.. I tried various methods including:

`CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero; for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews)
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;`

I think the problem is because it is built by Interface Builder but the UIScrollView contains other elements as well so I can't create it programmatically. I was hoping someone could help me on this.

**UPDATE 1**: I have both the UIView and the UIScrollView's heights set to 1024 from the Interface Builder.

**UPDATE 2 (FIX)**:
I was able to fix this problem by issuing a timer at the end of the `viewDidLoad` method like so:

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.00001 target:self selector:@selector(resizeScrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]`

and then resizing it in the `resizeScrollView` method here:

`-(void)resizeScrollView {
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView* view in scrollView.subviews)
    {
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
    }
    [scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, scrollViewHeight-50))];
}`

Thanks for all the help!

**NOTE**: This solution was inspired by Maniac One's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change 
scrollview.contentSize 
according to your program requirement in 'viewDidScroll'  delegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
  {
  }
  if you are getting new values for textfield while scrolling

Comment: Actually, the content changes just when the view loads in `viewDidLoad` and then I adjust the size of the UITextView according to its content by creating it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

`scrollView.contentsize=textview.size`

Comment: This is not working. It still does nothing because there other elements other than the UITextView.

Comment: In that case you can use `scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(Addition of widths of all views in scrollView, Addition of heights of all views in scrollView) `

Comment: It still isn't working.. I am doing this in the viewDidLoad method, is this correct?

Comment: Using timer to resize the view isn't a good idea. Rather you can use [UITextView delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) methods.

Comment: You can use method `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView`